# What is a word describing the process of understanding that reality isn't utopian?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

In summarizing a novel where someone transitions from an idealistic to a more pragmatic worldview, what would a word for that realization be? Like the process of understanding reality often disappoints in a sense

Comment: "Growing up", perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest **disenchant**, which *Merriam-Webster* defines as—

> to free from illusion

If you are more comfortable with an idiom, this one from [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/amp/english/the-scales-have-fallen-from-someones-eyes) fits the bill nicely—

> The scales have fallen from someones eyes

Comment: To which idiom does the Collins link refer? I don't know why you removed it.

Comment: @Weather Vane— Sorry, I edited it again because I thought if one clicked the link, one would be able to access the answer. Please edit the answer if I have made a mistake. :)

Comment: Link-only answers are disapproved for at least two reasons I can think of. They are better used to *support* an answer.

Comment: Thank you, @Weather Vane. :)

Comment: works great, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest **[epiphany](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/epiphany)**.

Merriam-Webster is quite perspicuous when it comes to defining the term:

> (1): a usually sudden manifestation or perception of the essential nature or meaning of something
> (2): an intuitive grasp of reality through something (such as an event) usually simple and striking
> (3): an illuminating discovery, realization, or disclosure

Answer (score 0):

I can think of someone being [***disillusioned***](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/disillusion.html). But you could also use a more idiomatic expression like ***come down or back to earth*** or [***return to reality***](https://www.powerthesaurus.org/get_real/synonyms). Check the links for synonyms.